# Подсчет суммы через javascript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пжлст как реализовать

Есть первичное значение, например 1, его можно определять по умолчанию в javascript

Есть следующий селект

```
<select id="summa">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
<option value='6'>6</option>
<option value='7'>7</option>
<option value='8'>8</option>
<option value='9'>9</option>
<option value='10'>10</option>
</select>
```

Как при выборе значения в select'e выводить в блоке <div id="itogo"></div> сумму значения заданного по умолчанию и значением из select. Только сделать подсчет динамическим без кнопок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

идея такова. остальное под себя поправьте http://jsfiddle.net/EzNQt/1/

Comment: не силен в js но вроде уловил логику: при выборе значения в селекте оно просто подставляется в itogo, а где же суммирование с определенным значением? Может надо уточнить, допустим в блоке <div id="itogo">1000</div> уже прописано число, надо к нему приплюсовать  значение из селекте

Comment: @Денис Шамко, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли. Все работает

Comment: @Денис Шамко, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).